# Numpy append 3D vectors without flattening

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, append

l have the following vector

```
video_132.shape
Out[64]: (64, 3)
```

that l would to add to it a new 3D vector of three values

```
video_146[1][146][45]
```

such that

```
video_146[1][146][45].shape
Out[68]: (3,)
```

and

```
video_146[1][146][45]
Out[69]: array([217, 207, 198], dtype=uint8)
```

when l do the following

```
np.append(video_132,video_146[1][146][45])
```

l'm supposed to get

```
video_132.shape
Out[64]: (65, 3) # originally (64,3)
```

However l get :

```
Out[67]: (195,) # 64*3+3=195
```

It seems that it flattens the vector

How can l do the append by preserving the 3D structure ?

Comment: look at the code for !append`.  It flattens the inputs when you don't specify an axis.  It confuses too many users.  Avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visual simplicity let's rename `video_132` --> `a`, and `video_146[1][146][45]` --> `b`. The particular values aren't important so let's say

```
In [82]: a = np.zeros((64, 3))
In [83]: b = np.ones((3,))
```

Then we can append `b` to `a` using:

```
In [84]: np.concatenate([a, b[None, :]]).shape
Out[84]: (65, 3)
```

Since [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) returns a new array, reassign its return value to `a` to "append" `b` to `a`:

```
a = np.concatenate([a, b[None, :]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for `append`:

```
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

Note how `arr` is `raveled` if no axis is provided

```
In [57]: np.append(np.ones((2,3)),2)
Out[57]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2.])
```

`append` is really aimed as simple cases like adding a scalar to a 1d array:

```
In [58]: np.append(np.arange(3),6)
Out[58]: array([0, 1, 2, 6])
```

Otherwise the behavior is hard to predict.

`concatenate` is the base operation (builtin) and takes a list, not just two.  So we can collect many arrays (or lists) in one list and do one `concatenate` at the end of a loop.  And since it doesn't tweak the dimensions before hand, it forces us to do that ourselves.

So to add a shape (3,) to a (64,3) we have transform that (3,) into (1,3).  `append` requires the same dimension adjustment as `concatenate` if we specify the axis.

```
In [68]: np.append(arr,b[None,:], axis=0).shape
Out[68]: (65, 3)
In [69]: np.concatenate([arr,b[None,:]], axis=0).shape
Out[69]: (65, 3)
```